# How/why does GAE/Endpoints caching work?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Running on GAE devserver, I POST to my REST URL to insert a new row. I get back a JSON response reflecting the inserted item. If I then go to the API explorer and query the GET URL, the newly inserted item is missing. After 20 seconds or so, and 4 or 5 GETS, eventually the new item is included in the response.

The endpoint code is the default generated code.

Any ideas where this cache/async behaviour is coming from, and how I can remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's GAE's datastore's eventual consistency behavior.  It's well documented in the GAE docs.

You'll have to rewrite your GET queries to be fully consistent.

Here's a start:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: While I don't doubt the answer, I am curious why I'm seeing it in the devserver. Does the devserver deliberately delay the writes to emulate the live environment?

Comment: Good question.  The "old" devserver (pre 1.7.6 or so) defaulted to fully consistent behavior, you needed a commandline param to force it to simulate eventually consistent behavior.  The new devserver is the opposite and defaults to eventually consistent behavior.  You can use the --datastore_consistency_policy commandline flag to switch it and determine if this is really the cause: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver

Answer (score 1):

This is because of eventual consistency.

You can construct your queries to be strongly consistent as outlined here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

However, if you are simply performing a get, you should be using a key.get(). This is also strongly consistent and is the way you should be retrieving a single entity.